# Template NoReverseMatch exceptions, outside of Models

Tags: django, templates, exception

I am generating some Django template code on the fly, in order to display rows in tables that are not stored in 
a Django database and do not have models.  I know the database and I can introspect them if needed, but I don't want
to write code by hand.

For example, field PSOPRDEFN.OPRCLASS stores an **optional** reference to a particular row where PSCLASSDEFN.OPRID=PSOPRDEFN.OPRCLASS, essentially a foreign key relationship.  If there is no relationship PSOPRDEFN.OPRCLASS has one ' ' (space character) in it.

I also have a page for a given PSCLASSDEFN row, where the url is:

```
url(r'^(?i)permissions/(?P<CLASSID>[A-Z0-9_&]{1,50})/$',
'pssecurity.views.psclassdefn_detail',
name="psclassdefn_detail"),
```

Note that the ?P CLASSID regular expression does not allow for blanks which corresponds to gets stored in the PSCLASSDEFN table - I figure it's safer to limit what the user can put in the url request.

Back to my generated template: I want to hyperlink to the relation, if it exists.  I feed my home-grown template generator a json "directive" indicating what I want put into the template (**thanks for the inspiration, django-tables2**):

```
    ....
    {
        "colname": "LANGUAGE_CD"
    },
    {
        "urlname": "security:psclassdefn_detail",
        "colname": "OPRCLASS",
        "kwargs": [
            {
                "colname": "dbr",
                "accessor": "dbr"
            },
            {
                "colname": "CLASSID",
                "accessor": "inst.OPRCLASS"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
```

Some fairly trivial code generation then results in:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 fieldlabel" title="LANGUAGE_CD" >Language Code</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 fieldvalue text-left _fv_LANGUAGE_CD">{{inst.LANGUAGE_CD}}</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 fieldlabel" title="OPRCLASS" >Primary Permission List</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 fieldvalue _fv_OPRCLASS">
        {% if inst.OPRCLASS|slugify %}
        <a href="{% url 'security:psclassdefn_detail' dbr=dbr CLASSID=inst.OPRCLASS %}">{{inst.OPRCLASS}}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that started getting random Template url resolution errors when displaying **some** of the PSOPRDEFN data.  I eventually tracked it down to the blank OPRCLASS fields in some rows.

In order to avoid this I first added

```
{% if inst.OPRCLASS %}
<a ...></a>
{% endif %}
```

That didn't work because the field is not empty, it is blank (and therefore doesn't match the CLASSID regex).  So, this is where I read the filter docs again and found that slugify strips out blanks and non-alpha.

```
{% if inst.OPRCLASS | slugify %}
<a ...></a>
{% endif %}
```

Works, as a workaround.  The problem is that CLASSID only stores alphanum, but that's not always true for other fields.  I wouldn't mind introspecting the table column definition at template generation runtime to see what to do, but I need to find an appropriate way to disable url reversal, for only some rows.

Questions.  Is there a better filter, such as a |strip?  I suppose I could always build my own filter.

Even better, is there a tag to selectively catch NoReverseMatch' exceptions at template generation time?

```
{% try NoReverseMatch  %}
        <a href="{% url 'security:psclassdefn_detail' dbr=dbr CLASSID=inst.OPRCLASS %}">{{inst.OPRCLASS}}</a>
{% endtry %}
```

The reason I was so verbose in my description is because this is not something that can be worked around using Models.  And neither can I custom-tune the template by hand.  I find Django works quite well without models in most cases, but url reversing in templates can be quite brittle when a few rows of data do not match expectations.  Hardening it would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result of the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag to a variable.

```
{% url 'path.to.view' arg arg2 as the_url %}
{% if the_url %}
<a href="{{ the_url }}">link</a>
{% else %}
No link
{% endif %}
```

This syntax does not raise an exception if reversing the view fails.

Comment: Works on my test scenario.  Thanks!

Comment: update.  It works, most of the time.  But, **the_url** gets assigned to the general context namespace.  What that means is that, on the next pass, if the url does not resolve, **the_url** does not get assigned, but the previous successful resolution is available for the current pass.  i.e. you may get the last-computed url by mistake.  I tried to assign it to the current row, as in **as row.the_url** but that didn't work.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe The Django should be changed so that the url tag sets `the_url` to `None` in the context if it fails to reverse the url. A work around could be to wrap the code with a [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with) statement, i.e. `{% with the_url='' %}`.